# Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, xcode14.3

I am using Xcode 14.3.
iOS: 16.3 Device
Flutter version: 2.10.5
While running in device compile successfully but run time it crash and error is:
Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter.
also
Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

Expected : it will execute successfully.